# Microsoft IIS 10 - Apache Tomcat 7 reverse proxy Windows Authentication problem

Tags: tomcat, iis

I use IIS 10.0 as a reverse proxy of Tomcat 7.
IIS 10.0 use Windows Authentication.
When I run the javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest.getAuthType() method I get the null value.
When I run the javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest.getRemoteUser() method I get the null value.
Using IIS 6.1 with the same version of Tomcat everything works fine.
When I run the javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest.getAuthType() method I get "NTLM" string.
When I run the javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest.getRemoteUser() method I get the name of the user who authenticated with IIS.
The configuration of the two versions of IIS appears to be the same.
What could be causing the problem?

Comment: "I use IIS 10.0 as a reverse proxy of Tomcat 7", so what are you using? ARR or HttpPlatformHandler?

Comment: Sorry i don't understand the question.

Comment: Seems to be missing some AJP headers including:
? remote_user 0x03
? auth_type 0x04
which instead are present in the headers sent by IIS 6.1

Comment: You are using IIS6, in fact, since IIS7, there have been huge changes from the previous version of IIS. You use the windows authentication method, I found a reference, which may be helpful to you: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/authentication/windowsauthentication/